# How to force the HTTP Listener Connector to be one way?

Tags: java, mule, esb

In Mule 3.6, the new HTTP Listener Connector is meant to be a two way connection. My requirement is that this should be one way. I do not want to send any data back and I do not want the connection to wait for my Mule floHow do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want your HTTP Listener to be one-way you can place it in the async scope. For more information about this, you can check: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Async+Scope+Reference. HTH.